# CRON chown and chgrp to a directory from root user

Tags: cron, chown, chgrp

I am trying to change **group and owner** (from root to www-data)for a directory at each 5 min interval.

So I have set a cron on **root** user like `

```
0,5 * * * * sudo /bin/chown -R www-data /var/www/pdf/ && sudo /bin/chgrp -R www-data /var/www/pdf/
```

But it's not working .

Kindly help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> 0,5 * * * *   sudo /bin/chown -R www-data /var/www/pdf/ && sudo /bin/chgrp -R www-data /var/www/pdf/

First off, the `chgrp` is redundant, you can manage the same with the `chown` command itself.

So instead of doing `sudo /bin/chown -R www-data /var/www/pdf/ && sudo /bin/chgrp -R www-data /var/www/pdf/`, you can do `sudo /bin/chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/pdf`

Next instead of `0,5 * * * *` as your cron frequency, run it using `*/5 * * * *`

Finally, instead of adding cron to a `user's crontab` with `sudo` / to systemwide cron using `/etc/cron.d`, add it to the root user's crontab using

```
sudo crontab -e
*/5 * * * * /bin/chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/pdf/
```